# Actualizar un div, con un evento recibido de la BD

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Como están? estoy intentando refrescar un DIV que tiene datos traídos de una BD. Pero lo que pude hacer es únicamente refrescarlo por un tiempo, me gustaría solicitar ayuda (soy bastante nuevo) para refrescarlo cuando tenga un nuevo evento la BD. Si me pueden aconsejar como hacerlo. Este es mi código:

```
    <section id="caja">
    <div id="caja-central">
        <div>
            <?php include('.\Querys\userQuery.php') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

$(document).ready(function() {
var pageRefresh = 2000; //2 s
setInterval(function() {
refresh();
}, pageRefresh);
});

function refresh() {
$('#caja').load(location.href + " #caja");
}
```

Comment: Lo primero que debe quedar claro es el tipo de evento que necesitas. ¿Es unidireccional? Es decir, sólo el cliente escuchará cambios en el servidor, y no mandará de vuelta nada al servidor? En ese caso, necesitas un [SSE (server-sent event)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events). Si debe ser bidireccional, requerirás algo tipo [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

Comment: claro es unidireccional

Comment: pregunta, soy novato con js y jquery... sera que podre pedir algun ejemplo de como hacerlo?

Comment: [Aquí tienes un ejemplo completo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) que incluye el código que debes poner en tu archivo Javascript, así como el código que debes poner en el archivo PHP. Inténtalo y si hay algún problema nos dices.

Comment: @A.Cedano Pues no conocía eso del SSE, y desde que lo has dicho que lo he estado probando y me daba un retardo de casi un minuto en las respuestas el ejemplo de esa web, pero al final lo he podido solucionar (era por culpa del php-fpm y encontré la solución en [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707792/how-to-disable-buffering-with-apache2-and-mod-proxy-fcgi)) y ahora funciona en tiempo real :-)  Yo no me queria meter aun en websockets y te agradezco tu aporte pues me va a ir de fábula, es mucho más sencillo de usar, gracias.

Comment: que bueno, yo no he podido aun entenderle, no se donde tengo que poner mis datos que traigo de mi BD, y ponerlo en el div. Me esta quemando la cabeza un poco. :/

Comment: @MatiasTonnera De momento prueba [este ejemplo](https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/tree/main/server-sent-events) y hazlo funcionar en tu dominio. Si ves que no funciona ten un poco de paciencia, a mi me ha tardado un minuto en funcionar (que luego he arreglado).  Cuando consigas eso tan solo deberás modificar el archivo PHP de ese ejemplo con lo que quieras mostrar y llamarlo desde donde necesites usarlo.

Comment: te agradezco, lo intentare

Comment: Pude lograr hacer funcionar lo que deseaba, pero ahora estoy con tema de cache, me tarda unos 3 segundos en darme la respuesta de server a cliente.  hay alguna forma de optimizar y que sea a tiempo real?

Comment: Has probado de ponerle esta cabecera debajo de la del text/event-stream?  `header('Cache-Control: no-cache');`  Y si así tampoco te funciona prueba con esta otra tambien: `header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');` (o con ambas a la vez)

Comment: Agregue el header('X-Accel-Buffering: no'); pero aun asi me tarda esos segundos, en el enlace que pusiste que lo solucionaste y te quedo en tiempo real, cual seria la solucion esa? a lo mejor me sirve tambien.

Comment: A ver, por lo que pude averiguar, en mi caso estaba usando un servidor apache con http/1 y para usar el SSE recomiendan el http/2... ¿el sitio donde lo estás poniendo cual de ellos usa?

Comment: Y la solución que me funcionó (aunque al final lo tuve que quitar porque me estropeó otras cosas) fue la de poner `<Proxy "fcgi://localhost/" enablereuse=on flushpackets=on max=10></Proxy>` en el virtualhost de mi apache correspondiente a mi dominio, pero eso era porque ademas estoy usando php-fpm, cosa que no se si es tu caso tampoco.

Comment: por cierto, para asegurarte que es en tiempo real debes hacerlo con el ejemplo ese que te manda la fecha con los segundos, pues si lo estas probando con código tuyo quizas esos 3 segundos es lo que tarda en procesarse realmente y enviar su salida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Javascript existen los [Eventos Enviados por el Servidor (SSE por sus siglas en ingles: Server-Sent Events)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events). Son eventos unidireccionales, es decir, el servidor los emite, el cliente los recibe y decide qué hacer con esos datos, pero el servidor no recibe nada de vuelta desde el cliente (para comunicaciones bidireccionales puedes usar [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)).

El uso de SSE es muy simple.

#### En el cliente

En primer lugar, olvídate de Ajax... estamos pasando a otro universo.

Desde el cliente, necesitas crear un objeto `EventSource`, pasando como parámetro el archivo de servidor que va a generar actividad allí:

```
var evtSource = new EventSource("ssedemo.php");
```

Y luego añadir un listener para saber cuándo hay mensajes:

```
evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
  /*
     Aquí lo que vayas a hacer con e
     que será lo que el servidor haya emitido
     y eso puede ser un json, texto, lo que sea
  */
}
```

También puedes escuchar eventos, usando `addEventListener()`. Esto te permitirá por ejemplo hacer cosas distintas según el nombre del evento ocurrido en el servidor (ver el apartado **eventos nombrados** en la documentación):

```
//En el servidor habrás debido poner: echo "event: ping\n";
evtSource.addEventListener("ping", function(e) {    
  var obj = JSON.parse(e.data);
  //Usar obj
}, false);
```

#### En el servidor

Un archivo que genere actividad, en el ejemplo lo hemos llamado `ssedemo.php` y asumimos que está en la misma carpeta que el archivo donde está el código del cliente. Que quede claro: debes usar dos archivos distintos, no mezclar todo en el mismo archivo.

La forma en que esa actividad se genere no viene al caso aquí. Puede ser lanzada por un cron, por un disparador de eventos de la bd o lo que sea. Lo cierto es que cuando algo cambie en ese archivo, el cliente lo va a recibir.

Tomando el mismo ejemplo de la documentación, el código quedaría así:

### Ejemplo

#### A. En el archivo del cliente

Vamos a tener un elemento `ul` con su id, y le iremos agregando un `li` en cada evento. Lo pararemos al llegar a diez eventos.

```
<ul id="eventList"></ul>

<script>

    var eventList=document.getElementById('eventList');
    var evtSource = new EventSource("ssedemo.php");
    var evtCount=0;
    evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
        evtCount++;
        var newElement = document.createElement("li");
        newElement.textContent = `message: ${evtCount} ${e.data}`;
        if (evtCount==10){
          evtSource.close();
          newElement.textContent = `close: ${evtCount} ${e.data}`;
        }
        eventList.appendChild(newElement);
    }

</script>
```

#### B. En el archivo del servidor (`ssedemo.php`)

Es el mismo código del ejemplo de la documentación. Genera mensajes cada X tiempo. Nótese el encabezado: `Content-Type: text/event-stream`. Puedes hacer un uso más avanzado, como emitir eventos nombrados, etc (consultar la documentación al respecto).

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");

$counter = rand(1, 10);
while (1) {
  // Every second, sent a "ping" event.

  echo "event: ping\n";
  $curDate = date(DATE_ISO8601);
  echo 'data: {"time": "' . $curDate . '"}';
  echo "\n\n";

  // Send a simple message at random intervals.

  $counter--;

  if (!$counter) {
    echo 'data: This is a message at time ' . $curDate . "\n\n";
    $counter = rand(1, 10);
  }

  ob_flush();
  flush();
  sleep(1);
}
```

En el archivo del cliente (A) deberás ver los `li` que se irán agregando al elemento `ul`, algo así:

```
message: 1 This is a message at time 2022-11-25T19:31:30-0500
message: 2 This is a message at time 2022-11-25T19:31:40-0500
message: 3 This is a message at time 2022-11-25T19:31:48-0500
message: 4 This is a message at time 2022-11-25T19:31:54-0500
message: 5 This is a message at time 2022-11-25T19:32:01-0500
message: 6 This is a message at time 2022-11-25T19:32:04-0500
message: 7 This is a message at time 2022-11-25T19:32:08-0500
message: 8 This is a message at time 2022-11-25T19:32:11-0500
message: 9 This is a message at time 2022-11-25T19:32:20-0500
close: 10 This is a message at time 2022-11-25T19:32:27-0500
```