# ¿ como puedo hacer para cuando realice una oferta el botón se deshabilite y cuando otro usuario haga otra oferta se habilite el botón?

Tags: php, html, mysql

estoy haciendo un sitio web de subastas en linea y quiero que al realizar una oferta ya no pueda ofertar hasta que otro oferte entonces ocupo que el botón se deshabilite para ese usuario que ya oferto para que no pueda ofertar de nuevo hasta que otro usuario oferte si me entiendo?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero el botón ofertar se deshabilite cuando realice la oferta el usuario actual y se habilite ya cuando haya otra oferta de otro usuario

````
<?php
 if( ($_SESSION['rol'] == 'Comprador') && ($rst['Estado']=='Subasta') ){?>
                                              <form class = "form-inline" action="app/add_puja.php" method="POST">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="idsubasta" value="<?php echo $idsubasta; ?>">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="envioart" value="<?php echo $rst['Nombre']; ?>"> 
                                                <input type="hidden" name="flimite" value="<?php echo $rst['Tiempo_Fin']; ?>">                     
                                                <input type="hidden" name="vmin" value="<?php echo $rst['Valor_Minimo']; ?>">

                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input type="number" name="oferta" class="form-control" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event)" min="<?php echo $rst5['segumayor']+$incremento;?>" value="<?php echo $rst5['segumayor']+$incremento;?>" required>
                                                </div>
                                                <button type="submit" id= "ofertar" class="btn btn-warning" name="ofertar">Ofertar</button>
                                              </form>
                                        <?php }?>  ```este es el codigo donde esta el boton
````

este es el codigo donde manda al hacer clic

```
<?php if (isset($_POST["ofertar"])){
        $puja = new Puja();
        //Si el usuario quiere ofertar por un producto

            if($_POST["oferta"]< $_POST["vmin"]){
                $_SESSION['msgError1'] = "<center>EL valor de oferta es menor al valor minimo.</center>";
            }
            else{               
                $puja->setIdsubasta($_POST["idsubasta"]);
                
                $rst = $puja->PujaMayor();
                $rst = $puja->PujasegundaMayor();
                $pujamayor = $rst['mayor'];
                $pujasegundamayor = $rst['segumayor'];
                $oferta = $_POST["oferta"];
                $envioart = $_POST["envioart"];
    
                if($oferta <= $pujasegundamayor){
                    $_SESSION['msgError1'] = "<center>EL valor debe ser mayor al de la puja actual.</center>";
                }
                else{
                    $puja->setUsername($_SESSION["username"]);       
                    $puja->setValor($oferta); //POST CAJA TEXTO oferta
                    $reg = $puja->Registrar();
                    if($reg){   
                        try{
                            $nombres = $_SESSION['apellidos']." ".$_SESSION['nombres']; 
                            $_SESSION['msgSuccess1'] = "<center>Puja Enviada.</center>";
```

¿Qué podría hacer?, soy principiante en esto, me gustaría que me pudieran ayudar.

[image: asi quedaría ya deshabilitado]

asi quedaría ya deshabilitado el botón y el input
que no se pueda ofertar de nuevo hasta que otro usuario realice una oferta

Comment: Tenndrías que enviar peticiones asíncronas constantemente para verificar si el usuario logueado es igual al último usuario que ofertó y con esto cambiar el estado del botón. Puedes usar `ajax` o `fetch` para lograrlo.

Comment: Lo ideal es programar eventos en la base de datos o disparadores que se activen a cada inserción (cada oferta nueva). Esos eventos notificarían a todos los clientes que estén suscritos. Necesitarás para ello algo como [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) o bien [Eventos Enviados por el Servidor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/570657/29967) que son bastante fáciles de implementar, pero tienen la limitación de que no puedes establecer una comunicación bidireccional como sí puedes hacer con Websockets, pero eso lo puedes solventar mediante Ajax o Fetch.